# What Macintosh programs are people using to create textures and artwork for iPhone / iPad development?

Tags: iphone

What Macintosh programs are people using to create textures and artwork for iPhone / iPad development?

Comment: Not programming related.

Comment: Not a programming question. I imagine "Photoshop" is the likely answer.

Comment: It's really best to use a vector graphics editor like Illustrator or Inkscape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is....

## Photoshop

Comment: ...and Illustrator too (probably).

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Photoshop and [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) (An Open Source vector graphics editor).